# PYTHON: How to pass asterisk (*) as command line argument

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python script that search words in files.
If I pass `txt` it will only look in files with **.txt** extension, but I want to pass `*` as argument to search in **every** files.

```
if sys.argv[4] == "*"
```

Don't work and if I try

```
print sys.argv[4]
```

It print the name of the script

```
find.py
```

But not the same way as

```
print sys.argv[0]
```

As it will return

```
./find.py
```

So, someone already had this problem and, of course, solved it ?

Comment: This is not a python question, it's a question on how to use your shell, and you haven't told us which one you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, I use Mate Terminal but I want something that work for every terminal or most of them.
Also thanks for the two peoples who down vote this question, I forgot that you can't be a beginner in SO .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your **shell** attaches meaning to `*` as well. You need to escape it when calling your script to prevent the shell from expanding it:

```
python find.py \*
```

`sys.argv[0]` is the exact name passed used to run the script. That can be a relative path (`./find.py`, `../bin/find.py`) or an absolute path, depending on how it was invoked. Use `os.path.abspath()` to normalize it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I forgot to said that I'm searching a fix in the python script and not a workaround for the command line.
But thanks a lot and thanks for tip about os.path.abspath().

Comment: @VivienG: **There is no fix for that**, other than accepting that Python will be passed *all names* in the current working directory by the shell, instead of `*`.